# OpenXML for template merge in Word

Tags: openxml-sdk, aspose.words

I'm evaluating to see whether we can use OpenXML SDK for merging template with data. We are using Aspose Words third party solution and we observed it is slow for large documents. For a document of size 20 MB, Aspose takes around 1 sec to max 4 seconds but we observed Open XML takes 50 msec - 1 sec to fill a table with 3000 rows of data. I see the limitation of OpenXML is around TOC refresh and fields update. Let's say If the template don't have any TOC but only page number in footer then is it ok to use OpenXML?

Comment: 20MB for DOCX document is really large size. What approach do you use to fill the document with data using Aspose.Words? The document processing time depend on many factors, such as the input document format, output document format, whether it is required to update field in the document or not, whether it is required to build document layout or not, the document structure complexity etc. I would suggest to post a question in Aspose.Words support forum and provide test document for testing https://forum.aspose.com/c/words/8/